# Need to fetch the table details using stored procedure when we give table name as input

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE test_table 
(
    col1  NUMBER(10),
    col2  NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO test_table 
VALUES (1, 2);
```

I am writing a stored procedure wherein if I give a table name as an input, that should give me the table data and column details.

For example:

```
SELECT *   
FROM <input_table_name>;
```

But this causes an error that the SQL command has not ended properly even though I have taken care of this.

My attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test(iv_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
p_out_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
lv_str VARCHAR2(400);
lv_count NUMBER(1);
lv_table_name VARCHAR2(255):=UPPER(iv_table_name);
BEGIN

    lv_str := 'SELECT * FROM '||lv_table_name;
    
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO lv_count FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = lv_table_name;
    IF lv_count = 0 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Table does not exist');
    ELSE
        OPEN p_out_cur FOR lv_str;
    END IF;
END sp_test;
```

Tool used: SQL developer(18c)

Comment: A procedure, that returns table's content, is called `select` statement. If you want to perform this operation within SQL or PL/SQL code you have to explicitly specify all the structures for target object (column names, their types) upfront, because the compiler should know if the code is valid at compile time. So there's no any dynamic code here and plain `select` will do the same. If you want to pass a result to some external code (for example, Java), then you may use plain `select` without unnecessary complications alao

Comment: @astentx Yes correct it should be the ideal case but I got a requirement to write a procedure only so was wondering whether this is possible using procedure or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dynamic SQL, you do NOT terminate statement with a semicolon.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM '||lv_table_name||';';
                                                 -----
                                                 remove this
```

Anyway, you won't get any result when you run that piece of code. If you really want to see table's contents, you'll have to switch to something else, e.g. create a function that returns ref cursor.

---

Sample data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test_table;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1          2
         3          4
```

Procedure you wrote is now correct:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test (iv_table_name  IN     VARCHAR2,
  2                                       p_out_cur         OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  3  AS
  4     lv_str         VARCHAR2 (400);
  5     lv_count       NUMBER (1);
  6     lv_table_name  VARCHAR2 (255) := UPPER (iv_table_name);
  7  BEGIN
  8     lv_str := 'SELECT * FROM ' || lv_table_name;
  9
 10     SELECT COUNT (1)
 11       INTO lv_count
 12       FROM all_tables
 13      WHERE table_name = lv_table_name;
 14
 15     IF lv_count = 0
 16     THEN
 17        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Table does not exist');
 18     ELSE
 19        OPEN p_out_cur FOR lv_str;
 20     END IF;
 21  END sp_test;
 22  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_rc    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3     l_col1  NUMBER (10);
  4     l_col2  NUMBER (10);
  5  BEGIN
  6     sp_test ('TEST_TABLE', l_rc);
  7
  8     LOOP
  9        FETCH l_rc INTO l_col1, l_col2;
 10
 11        EXIT WHEN l_rc%NOTFOUND;
 12
 13        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_col1 || ', ' || l_col2);
 14     END LOOP;
 15  END;
 16  /
1, 2              --> contents of the
3, 4              --> TEST_TABLE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

A function (instead of a procedure with the OUT parameter):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sf_test (iv_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  3  AS
  4     lv_str         VARCHAR2 (400);
  5     lv_count       NUMBER (1);
  6     lv_table_name  VARCHAR2 (255) := UPPER (iv_table_name);
  7     l_rc           SYS_REFCURSOR;
  8  BEGIN
  9     lv_str := 'SELECT * FROM ' || lv_table_name;
 10
 11     SELECT COUNT (1)
 12       INTO lv_count
 13       FROM all_tables
 14      WHERE table_name = lv_table_name;
 15
 16     IF lv_count = 0
 17     THEN
 18        raise_application_error (-20000, 'Table does not exist');
 19     ELSE
 20        OPEN l_rc FOR lv_str;
 21     END IF;
 22
 23     RETURN l_rc;
 24  END sf_test;
 25  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT sf_test ('liksajfla') FROM DUAL;
SELECT sf_test ('liksajfla') FROM DUAL
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Table does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.SF_TEST", line 18


SQL> SELECT sf_test ('TEST_TABLE') FROM DUAL;

SF_TEST('TEST_TABLE'
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1          2
         3          4


SQL>
```

Comment: Ok but cursor I can use it in stored procedure also. Will this work if I use in stored procedure

Comment: Sure; it's *just another cursor* - fetch from it and do whatever you want with data it returns.

Comment: I have modified the original stored procedure but when I am calling this procedure by creating of test function and then writing a select query with the table name parameters it is throwing an error Encountered the symbol "SELECT"

Comment: You didn't post that piece of code; anyway, I edited the answer and added some more info - have a look.

Comment: Thanks for this but I need to select all the columns of a table. I had posted for just one test table but if I give any tables it should give me the content of that table

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood. You posted the code for testing the existing procedure logic. Right?

Comment: If you want to have a "generic" solution, then consider a **function** instead of a procedure; have a look at edited answer.

Comment: Actually I was looking for stored procedure to handle this task. Is this not feasible with Stored procedure

Comment: I'm afraid not. See what astentx commented (below your question).